# unit testing complex pyspark sql case statements with multiple subqueries

Tags: python, sql, unit-testing, pyspark, pytest

I've inherited pyspark code which is overly complicated and I need some advice on breaking it down for unit testing purposes.  I've looked all over the web & Stack Overflow and can't quite get the answer I'm looking for so here goes .....

## Problem

The code is huge and complicated. There are functions doing way to much, coupled, not easy to follow, with duplicated logic and so on. Most of it is in SQL. I'm trying to break it down so I can write functions to unit test using pytest but I'm struggling on the best way to break down the SQL case statements with multiple subqueries. Here's a rough example to get an idea of what I mean (I probably haven't closed off the CASE statements properly here so don't read too much into it. Was just trying to get an example):

```
CASE WHEN cond1 THEN logic1
     WHEN cond2 THEN 
                    CASE WHEN cond3 THEN logic2 ELSE logic3 END
     WHEN cond4 THEN 
                    CASE WHEN cond5 THEN
                                        CASE WHEN cond6 THEN logic4 ELSE logic5 END
                                    ELSE
                                        CASE WHEN cond7 THEN logic6
                                                ELSE CASE WHEN cond8 THEN logic5 END 
                                        END 
                                    END
                            WHEN cond9 THEN
                                        CASE WHEN cond10 THEN logic3
                                            ELSE
                                                CASE WHEN cond11 THEN logic5 END
                                            END
                            ELSE logic6 END END 
END as name_of_column
```

As you can see, lots of conditions, subqueries, and repeating logic. The actual code I'm working with has many case statements much more complex than this included in huge joins, all together as one big query so there is lots to break down.

I've created individual functions per logic (logic1, logic2, logic3 and so on) so these are isolated and testable. I'm happy with this bit.

## What I've tried1 - creating many 'with columns' using native pyspark code

The query above is basically saying if cond1 = True then run logic1 and so on. So my thought was to create a function to coalesce the results like a hierarchy, taking the result from the first condition to produce a non-null result. Unfortunately my poor pyspark skills are hindering me from writing the solution as well as I'd like.

I've created a list of lists containing conditions and results ......
list_of_conditions = [[condition1, result1], [condition2, result2], [condition3, result3]]
and the following functions to create individual columns from each and then concatenate into one:

```
def condition_result(df, col_name, cond, result):
  return df.withColumn(col_name, when(cond, result).otherwise(None))


def apply_all_hirearchy_conditions(df, name, lst):
  hirearchy_cols = []
  for n, cond_result in enumerate(lst):
    col_name = "hirearchy_col"+str(n)
    hirearchy_cols.append(col_name)
    df = df.transform(condition_result, col_name, cond_result[0], cond_result[1])
  return df.withColumn(name, coalesce(*hirearchy_cols)).drop(*hirearchy_cols)


df = apply_all_hirearchy_conditions(df, "my_new_col", list_of_conditions)
```

It works, but it's rubbish, and I hate it because it creates individual columns per condition (hirearchy_col0, hirearchy_col1, hirearchy_col3 and so on), then coalesces and deletes them.

The upside is I can now test individual conditions (condition_result function), individual logic (functions per logic1, logic2, logic3 etc), and all conditions together (apply_all_hirearchy_conditions function).

There must be a better way to do this though.

## What I've tried2 - SQL string

Building an SQL string from the list of conditions by looping and concatenating. Something like:

```
string="CASE "
for i in list_of_conditions:
    string += "WHEN "+ i[0] + " THEN " i[1]
string += " END"
df.withColumn("my_new_col", expr(string))
```

I didn't like the idea of having to append to a string, and I was having trouble getting the logic1/logic2 functions to work.  It's also harder to test individual conditions I think.

## common issue

Also another issue for both of my attempts above is the conditions in the list (list_of_conditions) have to be repeated for subqueries. Imagine this really oversimplified CASE statement with subquery:

```
CASE WHEN df.col1.isin('1', '2') THEN
     CASE WHEN df.date_col > current_monthend_date THEN df.date_col
          ELSE logic1_func()
     END
END
```

The list would look like this, with repeated expressions:

[df.col1.isin('1', '2') & (df.date_col > current_monthend_date), df.date_col],
[df.col1.isin('1', '2') & (df.date_col <= current_monthend_date), logic1_func()],

Again, not great when we've got loads of subqueries. Although at least it means each condition is uncoupled and testable in isolation.

Anyway, any help is greatly appreciated. It has taken me ages to get this far. In the mean time I'll see if I can get a working example and post it so it can be run.

Comment: I'm starting to think it'll be easier just to put the whole case statements into individual functions using expr and not deal with the lists at all. Something like:

def create_col_rick:
    df.withColumn("rick", expr("CASE WHEN ....... THEN .... END"))

Means each column will have it's own function but the individual conditions are coupled and will be harder to test, but it will be easier to read.  So I'd have to create a single pytest unit test for the whole column and make sure my test data will cover all possible combinations. 
I'll have to work out how to run functions from sql too.